# Update 'Recommend Deletion' text to add 'Please consider deleting your post.'

Tags: feature-request

In Recommend Deletion, the

> This is a "thank you" comment

has text as

> “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the
>   answers that you find helpful.”

I think it should also add `'Please consider deleting your post'`. I think this will help the user understand as to what they should do now, and it will be more informative (educating) to them.

Comment: That might come across as patronizing. Like a slightly more polite way of saying ["Your post is bad and you should feel bad."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG2KMkQLZmI) The delete link is right there - I think most users will know to delete their own posts if the review process hasn't already gotten to it.

Comment: @BoltClock, Yeah this might happen. I think `Please consider` would take the edge off. Perhaps an even lighter note maybe?

Comment: The intended meaning of "Recommend Deletion" is not to recommend to the author to delete their post, but to recommend that the post be deleted in the review process.

Comment: The VLQ autocomments already get abused quite often either on posts that are absolutely fine (but get pattern-matched to something terrible by hasty reviewers because, for example, they're short and contain a link) or which *are* terrible but for a wildly reason to the one chosen by the reviewer. When the only harm done by this is comment noise, it's tolerable. But given the sloppiness of many reviewers, I'm concerned about the consequences of having high-rep users leaving stock comments telling new users who may not know better to delete their content.

Comment: @BoltClock I recommend those two comments be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @durron597: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might come across as patronizing. Like a slightly more polite way of saying ["Your post is bad and you should feel bad."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG2KMkQLZmI) The delete link is right there — I think most users will know to delete their own posts if the review process hasn't already gotten to it.

Furthermore, the intended meaning of "Recommend Deletion" is not to recommend to the author to delete their post, but to recommend that the post be deleted, whether by the author, or through the review process without having to go through them.

Comment: The rate of self-deletion of both questions and answers is in the single-digit percentages, and I think that's because people "abandon their post;" having been duly chastized about their content, they don't feel any further motivation to participate.  In other words, I don't think it's an education problem.

Comment: Just as I suspected.